# Travamento do programa ao execultar a função. Tkinter + Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

É o seguinte criei um simples programa para quebrar md5 numéricas, porem o mesmo trava quando clico em descrypter e só volta a funcionar quando encontra a hash, mas fica travado até encontrar e tem umas hash como a hash md5 de '81748856' que demora 5 minutos, e ele fica travado o tempo todo tem como fazer ele não travar e executar a função?

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
def decripter():
    from hashlib import md5
    import time
    a=str(h.get()).strip()
    if len(a)==32 and a.isdigit()==False and a.isalpha()==False and a.isalnum()==True:
        pass
    elif len(a) <32:
        lab1["text"]=f"\n\nTá faltando {32 - len(a)} caracteres!"
        lab1["font"]="Arial 9 bold"
        return
    else:
        lab1["text"]="\n\nTem certeza que isso é um MD5(number)?"
        lab1["font"]="Arial 9 bold"
        return
    inicio = time.time()
    n=0
    while(True):
        d= md5(str(n).encode()).hexdigest()
        if int((time.time()-inicio)) > 300:
            lab1["text"]=f"\nO tempo limite de {int(time.time()-inicio)}s se esgotou, a string não foi detectada!"
            lab1["font"]="Arial 9 bold"
            return
        if d==a:
            lab1["text"]=f"\nProcurando isso? '{n}'"
            lab1["font"]="Arial 11 bold"
            break
        else:
            n+=1

root.geometry("500x180")

root.title("Decry(MD5(num)) v1.0")

lab=Label(root, font="Arial 9 bold" , text="Bem vindo ao Decry(MD5(num)) na atual versão '1.0' \nO proposito principal desse programa é 'Descriptografar' hash Md5(number)\n\n").pack()


h=Entry(root, width=40,font="Arial 12 bold")
h.pack()
Button(root, text='Decrypter', command=decrypter).pack()
lab1=Label(root, font="Arial 9 bold" , text="\n\nTodos os direitos reservados a Code Ghost.")
lab1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: adendo: o command deveria ser **decripter** em vez de **decrypter**, visto o nome da função.

Comment: Valew. pela observação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É necessário chamar `root.update()` de tempos em tempos para atualizar a tela gráfica do `tkinter`... Se você não chamar essa função de vez em quando, o python vai ficar só calculando md5 dentro do seu loop, e o tkinter não vai ter tempo de atualizar a tela... Aí o windows vai achar que o programa travou e vai marcar a janela como "Não respondendo".

Uma forma é colocar dentro do seu loop:

```
while True:
    root.update()
    # ... resto do código aqui ...
```

Comment: Valew.. Resolveu o problema.